# Extract files from zip

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, zip, unzip

I'm trying to find a library to be able to simply extract files from a .zip archive.
Could you please advise me what library to use (and how to set it up, which files to include)?

I'm a beginner in C++ and I'm programming on Win32 using Visual Studio 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zLib is your best bet. It can be found here: [zLib website](http://zlib.net/).

Look in the `contrib\vstudio` folder for the visual studio projects. The easiest way to use it, is via minizip, located in the `contrib\minizip` folder.

Comment: I've compiled zlib 1.2.6 and got zlibwapi.dll/.lib,zlibstat.lib
Then tried to compile minizip and got a bunch of errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use the minizip headers, but link to the appropriate zlib for your crt.

Answer (score 2):

What about libzip? Even easier to use than using zlib directly.
http://www.nih.at/libzip/

Answer (score 0):

Since you say your a beginner, I don't think that zLib will be that friendly to you.
I suggest looking at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-clean-elegant-simple-C-Win32). It lets you easily add zip functionality to your code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is it that you find difficult about zlib? It compiles as a visual studio project that produces a library and headers.

Comment: @RitchMelton I don't find anything about zLib difficult myself. Perhaps, I was underestimating the asker's familiarity with c++ and suggested a nonstandard simpler alternative.

Comment: Ok, I wondered if I was overlooking some difficulty. Well, other than dependency management in C/C++ is a chore.